# How to make dns lookup faster with okhttp?

Tags: android, okhttp

I have used new `OkHttp` `EventListener` to debug why my request takes so long time. And there were these results:

```
0,000 callStart
0,027 dnsStart
5,189 dnsEnd
5,359 secureConnectStart
5,907 secureConnectEnd
5,910 connectEnd
5,921 connectionAcquired
5,925 requestHeadersStart
5,930 requestHeadersEnd
5,938 responseHeadersStart
6,181 responseHeadersEnd
6,189 responseBodyEnd
6,233 connectionReleased
```

As you can see, the time from `dnsStart` and `dnsEnd` takes about 5 seconds. How can I decrease this value? Are there any ways to warm up dns lookup or cache or something else?

Comment: Seems the DNS lookup on your system is slow (independent of okhttp). Do you experience the same delays in other situations?

Comment: I have checked it on other device with 3g network, the dns lookup takes about 2 seconds, but I think it is also too much @Henry

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, dns lookup takes 5 sec sometimes. Have you found the reason?

Comment: For example your sim-card has dns server of far away region @AndreyRankov

Comment: In my case it's sometimes happening even on fast wi-fi network. How this delay can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can try write a custom dns resolver, see https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/-builder/dns/.

But I suggest only do this when you detect dns lookup time is long.

Comment: An example would have added great value